# How to change the partition scheme in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I've currently created a partition scheme / function in my database, and applied it to a number of tables. It has worked perfectly, and I've reached the results I needed.

The issue is, if I want to extend the partition function, I have to change the partition scheme as well, every single time..

Currently, the partition scheme is defined as follows:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [Stores]
    AS PARTITION [StoreSplitter]
    TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [... etc ...], [PRIMARY])
GO
```

After reading MSDN, I realised I should have created it like this:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [Stores]
    AS PARTITION [StoreSplitter]
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
GO
```

In this case, all partitions would use the same store, and I don't have to change it every time, to support another partition.

Is there any way to alter the existing partition to use `ALL TO ([PRIMARY])` without recreating the whole thing, or is that just wishful thinking? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is. If there was a way to change this behaviour, I'd expect it would be an additional option in [ALTER PARTITION SCHEME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190347.aspx), so that you could specify that the NEXT USED that you've just supplied should gain the same status as specifying ALL in [CREATE PARTITION SCHEME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179854.aspx):

> If ALL is specified, the sole file_group_name maintains its NEXT USED property for this partition_function_name

But I'm not seeing such an option.

Comment: That's unfortunate.. I was hoping for someone to prove me wrong :)